# Ito's Lemma Applied to Kinked Function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, singularity, continuity

Consider an SDE for an Ito process $X_t$ with drift and diffusion $(\mu_t, \sigma_t)$ which exhibits a strong solution. Consider also a function $f(x)$ which exhibits a simple kink singularity at some point $c$. For example
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
ax \hspace{53pt} \text{ if } x\leq c \\
ac + b(x - c) \hspace{7pt} \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $a \neq b$.

How would one apply Ito's lemma the process $Y_t = f(X_t)$?

Over the the majority of the domain, the standard version of Ito's lemma holds, but at the singular point the function is not differntiab

Comment: There's no way you can apply the Ito formula to a discontinuous function. But if $c=0$, there's the Tanaka formula.

Comment: I'm not sure Tanaka's equation applies. Tanaka specifies the dynamics of a process, where those dynamics are discontinuous. Here the dynamics are continuous, but the function not. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: You still do not have a kink singularity. You have a jump of size $(b-a)c$. In the question you are concerned about non-differentiable points, in the comment and formula the function is not continuous. Please make your language consistent.

Comment: @LutzL Sorry, you're correct. I've edited the question to be consistent with the situation I'm describing. I was thinking $c=0$, but wrote the more general case without thinking.

Comment: I've found the papers "Quadratic Covariation and an Extension of Ito's formula" by Follmer, Protter, and Shiryaev,  and  "On Ito's Formula for Multidimensional Brownian Motion" by Follmer and Protter get me most of the way there using weak derivatives. However, calculating the quadratic covariation is not straight forward to me at first glance...